# Codeigniter clone table with active record or dbforge

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, dbforge

Is there a way to implement:

```
CREATE TABLE sample LIKE master;
```

using either Codeigniter active record or dbforge?

The reason being is that this is being executed from an administration panel; the admin is given a form and the new table name is captured from a POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
$tablename = $_POST['tblname'];
$mastertable = $_POST['mastertable']
$this->db->query("CREATE TABLE $tablename LIKE $mastertable");
```

To copy data

```
$query = $this->db->get($mastertable);
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
      $this->db->insert($tablename,$row);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the new table name is generated from a POST.

Comment: Corrected query: $this->db->query("CREATE TABLE $tablename LIKE $mastertable");